# dropdown disappears after selection in multiInput() under dropdown() in shinywidget

Tags: r, shiny

when I click the selection everytime, the drop download box close automaticlly.

Please how to keep the drop box open ?

Great Thanks

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
ui <- fluidPage(
dropdownButton(
label="Close after click",
style = "unite",
icon = icon("gear"),
multiInput('test','test',choices = letters)
)
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: it didn't disappear on my local, which shiny version do you use ?

Comment: If it closes for you after each selection, a workaround is shown in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68864740/how-to-stop-dropdownbutton-closing-with-every-selectinput-selection/68869748#68869748)

Comment: thanks @SametSökel, my shiny ver is 1.6.0, shinyWidgets version is 0.6.0, R version is 4.1.0, PC is windows10.

Comment: thanks @YBS, I saw that answer before.  Both dropdown and dropdownBotton get the same result. And I found the dorp box doesn't disappear in all widget s. In some widgets  it keep therew.

Comment: Hence, use `toggleDropdownButton`, as a workaround.